# How to intercept thickbox click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

I got that script and it is never called (I tried more specific that a.thickbox with no success):
How can I intercept the thickbox clicking ?

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.thickbox',   (e)=> {
    debugger;
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

My html is:

```
<a href="#TB_inline?&inlineId=editInterviewContainer" class="thickbox custom1">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you search for `jQuery(document).on('click', function) not working` there are no clear solution.

you can try the following, for static element

```
$('a.thickbox').on('click', (e)=> {
    console.log('static clicked');
});
```

for dynamic element

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.thickbox',   (e)=> {
    debugger;
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

and use both if you have static and dynamic thickbox element.